# how communicate to HC-05 Bluetooth module (RFComm/SPP) with Xcode in mac

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, bluetooth

I'm new to Xcode and I want to transfer data with HC-05 bluetooth module in my Xcode cocoa application.

My module is a Bluetooth to serial interface adapter. Is this possible? 
I can transfer data with this module by goSerial app in OS X.

What can I do?
Do you know any sample code or project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use ORSSerialPort library for communicating with your Serial port device and control it from your OSX application.